# Relay with arduino/microcontroller, diode needed?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller

I know that you have to place a diode in parallel with a relay to use with i/o on microcontroller. Would you have to do the same with a relay board such as......

http://www.sainsmart.com/module/acce...-pro-mini.html
http://www.sainsmart.com/module/acce...p-arduino.html

Comment: Your links somehow got abbreviated (the "...")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're still talking about the [relay module](http://www.sainsmart.com/8-channel-5v-solid-state-relay-module-board-omron-ssr-4-pic-arm-avr-dsp-arduino.html) from your other question, the answer is no, the diode is not required. This uses solid state relays which don't have a coil. It's that coil in an electromechanical relay that causes a voltage peak when switching off, against which the transistor has to be protected.

If you would be referring to one of the other modules using electromechanical relays, like [this one](http://www.sainsmart.com/module/sainsmart-4-channel-signal-relay-board-for-arduino-uno-mega-2560-r3-duemilanove.html), those have a protection diode on board.

Answer (score 2):

The links don't work in your question - if you are talking of [this product](http://www.sainsmart.com/module/acceleromete/sainsmart-2-channel-signal-relay-module-board-for-arduino-uno-mega-2560-r3-1280.html), then yes, they have diodes in parallel with the coils - I couldn't find an "official" schematic, but on the 2-channel version I found this picture:

[image: Relay]

You can see a 4148 (D3) across the coil. Also the relay is driven by Q1, not your Arduino pin, so it requires much less current and adds "layer" of protection.

If it's this: http://www.sainsmart.com/module/acceleromete/arduino-pro-mini.html then it has a similar arrangement, but adds an optocoupler for isolation (note this will need a higher drive current than the others, 15-20mA according to the page):

[image: RelayIso]

If it's one of the solid state versions, then as Steven notes the diode is not needed - these use a drive transistor also:

[image: RelaySS]

So basically, no, you don't need a diode for any of them, just drive directly from your Arduino pin.